# What do you call a counter with slot-machine-like animation?

Tags: terminology

What is a counter with slot-machine-like animation called?

Similar to this counter:

- http://flipclockjs.com/faces/counter

But with this kind of animation and look:

- https://matthewlein.com/experiments/slots.html
- http://kirkdev.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/simple-slot-machine-effect.html

What would this be called?
*I know how to implement it, just not sure about the correct name.

Comment: A counter with slot machine effect?

Comment: Why close this? It is perfectly reasonable to want to know what a ui-element is named. Not everyone is a native English speaker.

Comment: Read our [ask] page - it tells you what is an acceptable question. SO is for programming questions.  If you want the name of an UI element in English, you could either go to the English language Stack Exchange or the UX Stack Exchange.  This has very little (if any) to do with programming

Comment: Good point. Can this question be migrated to UX stack exchange?

Comment: Good question, maybe if you flag it for moderation a mod might be able to do that for you

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the people who voted to close it (I think), did so for other reasons that have nothing to do with the question. This question is clear and it is not asking to recommend a library, a book or a tutorial. Sometimes people are too eager to moderate. You suggestion is on spot thought. It is not directly related to programming, just naming something inside a program/project.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_counter

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Thanks! This indeed is the correct term.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a rolling-numbers counter (not turning or spinning).
You can find an existing example here (Odometer):

- http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/

Comment: That last bit of linked code provides a nice bit of simulation of the 'bounce' of a real slot machine,  - so to be more accurate you could add "rolling numbers counter with slot machine affect"